# Low Melting Point solder paste reflow profile adviced

Tags: soldering, reflow, solder-paste

I've found a low temp solder paste with a melting point of 140°C. I want to use it with some SMD parts. I've looked for some reflow profiles and didn't found nothing with this low melting point.

Can I just go without "soaking zone" and:
- linear ramp profile to 150-160° - 2.5°C/sec.;
- mantain for 20-30sec;
- linear ramp profile to 25° - 5°C/sec.

Or there is particular advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this low temperature will be activating the flux in the solder paste to make a good joint, it's not just the melting point of the solder.

You may hope that the lower temperature gives you more leeway for the ramp up. It's not just being gentle with the packages, the paste has to dry out as well.

So you need to look out the specification for the paste. If you don't have the spec, then do several experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your Paste. Every paste is different. 
You can try this (its a SnBi58 i guess)

Ramp about 2°C/s (ramp to soak about 50 sec)
110°C for about 70 - 110 sec
Peak 160°C for 60sec
cooldown 2-3 °C/s